# Minifiy javascript on the fly directly in function

Tags: javascript, minify, on-the-fly

I'm trying to minify my code on the fly, not install or use some tools like Uglify.js, ...

I would like something like :

```
function isInArray(array, element){
    return $.inArray(element, array) != -1;
}

var minifiedCode = minify(isInArray.toString());
```

I also tried with an Ajax request to use existing tools, but without success :

```
$.ajax({
        url:"https://javascript-minifier.com/raw?input=bob",
        type: "POST",
//      crossDomain: true,
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        success: function() { alert("Success"); },
        error: function() { alert('Failed!'); }
    })
```

I know it's quite strange, but I really need to create minified code on the fly to send it.

Thank you so much for your help, I haven't a clue to solve it :(.

Vanessa

Comment: What do you mean by "to send it"? Where does the original code come from, and where should the result go?

Comment: Regarding https://javascript-minifier.com/, you cannot use that with JSONP.

Comment: Hi Bergi, thanks a lot for your help. I need to pick up some functions from my original code ("isInArray" by example), minify them and then copy them into a file to download. All in javascript. At the end, I would have my "var minifiedCode" with the minified string of "isInArray" function. Am I clearer or still dark ?

Answer (score 0):

Elliot Foster has developed a tool to minify js on the fly: [Minified JavaScript, on the Fly!](https://www.fourkitchens.com/blog/article/minified-javascript-fly)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response, but this tool uses Uglify.js and works for a Drupal module, which I'm not using. I don't find how to use it for my request.

Comment: @Bergi, Yes of course I read some docs and try to understand how to use it, I would not ming you without reading before :(